# Access to Webform on maintenance mode

Tags: webforms

I've been trying to give access to a specific webform on maintenance mode without any success. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maintenance mode is for when you want to make sure requests don’t hit the database. Loading a webform requires database access, so even if you do find a way to do it, you’re always going to be fighting against the intent of the feature. It would make more sense to approach your problem a different way

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.